# LAV Splitter Source Filter stop after a few seconds

Tags: ffmpeg, directshow

I use LAV Splitter Source filter for playing media urls in directshow graph.
I don't why after a few seconds, it is stopped.

I read some articles (such as the following) about settings of this filter. but not worked.

[Understanding buffer/bitrate statistics in Media Player Classic](https://superuser.com/questions/131926/understanding-buffer-bitrate-statistics-in-media-player-classic/842244#842244)

[How to make MPC-HC to cache more aggressively](https://superuser.com/questions/842203/how-to-make-mpc-hc-to-cache-more-aggressively)

Any help would be appreciated.